# ActiveReports : The sections collection is invalid

Tags: .net, activereports, grapecity, rpx

I have an ActiveReport (.rpx), which was originally built in DataDynamics.ActiveReports Version 3. I have recreated the report in Grapecity.ActiveReports Version 16.3.1. The LoadLayout is working fine, but when I try to run the report, it is giving below error.

The sections collection is invalid. Please make sure that each Report/Page and Group Header has an associated Footer in the collection and that you have a detail section

Please Help

I have recreated the report in Grapecity.ActiveReports Version 16.3.1. The LoadLayout is working fine, but when I try to run the report, it is giving below error.

The sections collection is invalid. Please make sure that each Report/Page and Group Header has an associated Footer in the collection and that you have a detail section

Answer (score 0):

Jumping from 3.1 to 16.3.1 is huge. I reviewed all of the breaking changed between these versions and did not see a sections specific change that could cause this error.
Maybe you could find one. Here is a list of all online docs:
https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsnet/docs/
If you review the user guide of each version there is a section under Upgrade Reports called Breaking Changes.
For example:
https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsnet/docs/versions/v16/online/breaking-changes.html